# global variable and reference before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, runtime-error, global-variables

I'm trying to create an empty global pandas dataframe and then append to it within data processing functions. I'm having trouble figuring out what's going wrong. Here's a minimal example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def do_stuff_and_append_df():
    dt = datetime.now()
    row = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.tolist())
    row['datetime'] = dt
    row['pduType'] = 'blah'
    df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    print(df.head())

def main():
    # empty dataframe for appending
    header = ['datetime', 'pduType']
    global df 
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
    # Main loop
    try:
        while True:
            do_stuff_and_append_df()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nSaving and exiting.')
        df.to_csv('data.csv')

main()
```

I'm getting the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment`. Anybody know why I can't call `df` within this function?

Comment: which line throws that error ? Error should be in do_stuff_and_append method. See that you are accessing global object df without using `global df`

Comment: `row = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.tolist())` although I might have just figured it out after trying about 30 different combinations of things. Wasn't understanding where to make `df` global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to declare "global df" under the function do_stuff_and_append_df() as well.

Because the function do_stuff_and_append_df() doesn't know whether you are referring the local variable or Global variable.

Comment: Thanks, yeah kept trying one or the other without trying both

Answer (score 1):

try to add global declaration in `do_stuff_and_append_df`

```
def do_stuff_and_append_df():
    global df
```

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, *don't use a global variable*. Pass the desired data frame as an argument.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def do_stuff_and_append_df(df):
    dt = datetime.now()
    row = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.tolist())
    row['datetime'] = dt
    row['pduType'] = 'blah'
    df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    print(df.head())
    return df

def main():
    # empty dataframe for appending
    header = ['datetime', 'pduType']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
    # Main loop
    try:
        while True:
            df = do_stuff_and_append_df(df)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nSaving and exiting.')
        df.to_csv('data.csv')

main()
```

Comment: I know that's better form, but this was a minimal example and I actually don't have control over what the function returns because its wrapped by another function

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global var, put it explicitly in global scope:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def do_stuff_and_append_df():
    dt = datetime.now()
    row = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.tolist())
    row['datetime'] = dt
    row['pduType'] = 'blah'
    df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    print(df.head())

def main():
    # Main loop
    try:
        while True:
            do_stuff_and_append_df()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nSaving and exiting.')
        df.to_csv('data.csv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    header = ['datetime', 'pduType']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
```

Either that, or see chepner's answer. It's preferable that you *don't* use global vars